# Sand falling algorithm in sand sim cellular automata

Tags: c++, sdl, game-development

I'm working on a sand falling cellular autotoma and am having this issue updating sand. Everything is falling correctly, yet due to the fact it is updating from the bottom up, left to right, the sand does not flow to the left correctly. This is hard to explain in words, so here's a [gif](https://github.com/noahl25/particlesim/blob/main/test%202023-09-02%2015-41-00.gif).

This is the main code that handles sand falling:
The "particles" variable is a 2d vector of Particle object pointers. My program loops through the array from bottom up and left to right and applies this function to each coordinate.

```
void Manager::handleSand(int x, int y) {    
    if (inScreenBounds(x, y + 1) && particles[y+1][x] == nullptr) {
        particles[y][x] = nullptr;
        particles[y+1][x] = new Particle(ParticleType::Sand);
        return;
    }
    
    if (inScreenBounds(x - 1, y + 1) && inScreenBounds(x + 1, y + 1) && particles[y+1][x - 1] == nullptr && particles[y+1][x + 1] == nullptr) {
        bool dir = rand() %2;
        if (dir) {
            particles[y][x] = nullptr;
            particles[y+1][x - 1] = new Particle(ParticleType::Sand);
        }
        else {
            particles[y][x] = nullptr;
            particles[y+1][x + 1] = new Particle(ParticleType::Sand);
        }
        return;
    }
    
    if (inScreenBounds(x + 1, y + 1) && particles[y+1][x + 1] == nullptr) {
        particles[y][x] = nullptr;
        particles[y+1][x + 1] = new Particle(ParticleType::Sand);
        return;
    }

    if (inScreenBounds(x - 1, y + 1) && particles[y+1][x - 1] == nullptr) {
        particles[y][x] = nullptr;
        particles[y+1][x - 1] = new Particle(ParticleType::Sand);
        return;
    }       
}
```

If you're interested, you can access the rest of my code [here](https://github.com/noahl25/particlesim).

I tried double buffering, (seprating previous frame input and next frame) but that resulted in other undefined behavior (some particles wanted to go to the same place, making one override the other and delete one).

Comment: With just the code you posted, I see a potential mess of memory leaks with your usage of `new` and not one use of `delete`.   Setting a pointer to `nullptr` does not release the memory that was previously allocated.  In addition, I took a quick look at your base class for `Particle`, and it lacks a virtual destructor, thus it cannot be used safely polymorphically.

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried double buffering, but that resulted in other undefined behavior." ? Double buffering (maybe not quite the correct term?) seems like the obvious solution to me to avoid the processing order of the pixels affecting the result

Comment: As @PaulMcKenzie noticed, to avoid leaks prefer something like 
        `particles[y+1][x] = particles[y][x]; particles[y][x] = nullptr;` so that the particles *really* move. No creation, only moves

Answer (score -1):

Your algorithm is biased "to the right".
Suppose you have something like this (P=particle, R=rock):

```
 PP
  R
```

As you are scanning from the left you will then have first the fall of the left particle:

```
  P
 PR
```

and then :

```
 PRP
```

For the symmetric case:

```
 PP
 R
```

for the first particle have two choices: left or right... If you chose left, you fall into the same final result, but you also have the choice to the right which will give you:

```
  P
 RP
```

then:

```
 RPP
```

Your scanning induces a "right" bias, two symmetric cases will not give you the same result. You have to break that.
The most simple (and best?) choice is to randomly select the particles on a line and try to move them until there is no more possible move on that line.